# Make Caps Lock behave like in Windows

Tags: macos, keyboard

I use VoIP programs, and I use Caps Lock for Push-To-Talk (PTT) on those. The problem I experience is that when I push Caps Lock, I toggle the Push-To-Talk, which means that if I release Caps Lock, PTT is still on, and I have to push the button again to stop PTT. While on Windows this works fine, I have to hold down Caps Lock to talk. Any idea how I can make it so that I need to hold down Caps Lock on OSX as well?

Comment: Sounds like a Problem with your Voip-client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) (OSX app to manipulate caps lock) to rebind Caps Lock to F13, and I bound F13 to PTT, so now it works.

Comment: What is Seil? A link would be helpful (and prevent others from having to google it themselves).